# Ubuntu 16.04 install ElasticSearch 5.x, failed to start

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

On fresh install Ubuntu 16.04 I use next steps to install ElasticSearch 5.0.1 or 5.0.2 and ES failed to start. Does anyone know how can I run ES 5.x on Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.04?

1. su
2. add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
3. apt-get update
4. apt-get upgrade
5. apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
6. java -version
7. wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add -
8. apt-get install apt-transport-https
9. echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/5.x/apt stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-5.x.list
10. apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
11. service elasticsearch status

Elasticsearch 5.x failed to start on Ubuntu 16.04.
Does anyone know how can I run ES 5.x on Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.04?

I also try with the new version of Elasticsearch 5.1.1 with this few steps

1. su
2. apt-get purge elasticsearch
3. apt-get update
4. apt-get upgrade
5. apt-get install elasticsearch

-- new version elasticsearch 5.1.1 is installed

6. now if I check status I get this

> > service elasticsearch status

● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Active: inactive (dead)

```
 Docs: http : / / www.elastic.co
```

Dec 09 22:49:49 elastic systemd[1]: Stopped Elasticsearch.

Comment: also having continuous problems: connections keeps falling with ES 5.1 on ubuntu 16.04. ES 2 < on ubuntu 14.04 was working very fine. thinking to downgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The point is how to solve the problem presented here. I agree with you that the version 2.x & 1.x works fine on Ubuntu 14th & 16th.

Comment: Could you post a clearer and complete formatted output of status? Have you checked java does not failed for out of memory? check `dmesg` . If ES get killed (you will have `signal` as a "reason" in your ES status) , check how much heap is allocated. In 5.x. ES you can edit `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.option` file an modify `#-Xms2g
#-Xmx2g`

Comment: I do not follow you (@user305883). This is what I get when I run _free -m_
              **total**        **used**        **free**      **shared**  **buff/cache**   **available**
**Mem:**            974          80         294           5         600         707
**Swap:**          1021           0        1021

Comment: I was sceptical and thought I would not be able to find the answer to this question but your (@user305883) advice turned out to be a good. Thanks for help. I changed `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.option` `-Xms2g` and `-Xmx2g` to `#-Xms2g` and `#-Xmx2g` and after **service elasticsearch start** _ES_ run well on **Ubuntu 16.04**. This was right answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it possible to lock the memory using: `bootstrap.memory_lock: true` without setting the Heap size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sceptical and thought I would not be able to find the answer to this question but your (@user305883) advice turned out to be a good. Thanks for help.

I changed `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.option` `-Xms2g` and `-Xmx2g` to `#-Xms2g` and `#-Xmx2g` and on ubuntu terminal after I run this command

**service elasticsearch start**

*ES* start well on **Ubuntu 16.04**.

This was right answer. Thanks again to @user305883.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried uncommenting out `START_DAEMON=true` in `/etc/default/elasticsearch`?

Comment: There is no predefined option START_DAEMON=true in /etc/default/elasticsearch in version 5.1.1. Sorry, but this is not right answer.

Comment: Related discussion: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-start-elasticsearch-with-ubuntu-16-04/48730/9.

Comment: There is no that string in that file

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution that worked was to set Open JDK 8 as the default Java version. I was using `java-9-oracle` as the default version and despite uninstall/reinstall and altering the JVM options, ES 5.x couldn't be started. At the same time, ES 2.3 had no issues with Java 9.

You may change the default java version in Ubuntu by using 
`sudo update-alternatives --config java` command

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW,
I met the same issue after Ubuntu update. My Ubuntu `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, xenial`

I had `linux-image-extra-4.13.0-26`.

After update I got `linux-image-extra-4.13.0-31`.

And for some reason that update is broken.

I reverted kernel to previous `linux-image-extra-4.13.0-26` and Elastic started to work well again. Here is more about that https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-dead-recently-without-modify-anything/116839/2

I restarted Ubuntu.

During restart, clicked `Esc`. Entered Grub.

In Grub, selected `Advanced options` and selected previous kernel version.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on FreeBSD 10.x and 11.x - it helped the same solution - memory - the problem was that Elasticsearch 5.x did not provide any error message, no error log...